# How to calculate Laurent series in mathematica about some point $z_o$ and annulus $a<|z|<b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

> How to calculate Laurent series in mathematica about some point $z_o$ and annulus $a<|z|<b$?

I want to find the Laurent series in mathematica for given point and annulus. Can someone guide me correctly?

Comment: Maybe consider asking this question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please look here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197476/specifying-annular-region-while-obtaining-laurent-series